# For what value of a is the tangent plane parallel to the plane $x-y+z=1$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A surface is given by

$$z = x^{2}-2xy+y^2$$

(a) Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface at x = a, y = 2a.

I figured out this part, that the equation of a plane is $$2ax-2ay+z =  -a^2$$

(b) For what value of a is the tangent plane parallel to the plane $x-y+z=1$?

If we set (2a, -2a, 1) and (1, -1, 1) parallel to each other, we'll get the equation (2a, -2a, 1) = t (1, -1, 1). Hence, and we can solve for a: a = t/2.

Can t be any scalar multiple?

Comment: The third component fixes t

Comment: $(2a, -2a, 1) = t(1, -1, 1)$ so checking third component, $t = 1, a = 1/2$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see it for some reason.